# Extract a row from data frame using a row value using python

Tags: python, pandas

|col1|col2|col3|col4|

|nan |nan | fr |rt. |

|nan|MK1  |fg. |aa.  |

|nan.|MA1 |fl.  |f2|

Now we have a three rows with header col1,col2….

I want to extract row using certain value

Expected output :
MK1|fg|aa

MA1|f1 |f2

I used df[(df.values==‘MK1).any(axis=1)

For multiple value
df[(df.values ==‘MK1’) && (df.values==‘MA1)]

It is giving 0 rows with header .can someone help me to achieve this ?
Please don’t use loc or iloc

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use OR `|` instead of AND `&` because you are looking for `MK1` OR `MA1` in a column.

```py
df[(df["col2"] == "MK1") | (df["col2"] == "MA1")]
```

Comment: Hi ,thanks for the answer I am looking for both values and it has to extract two rows .

Comment: And I don’t want to use column name ,just extract it by mentioning row value

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is below. Has the advantage if number of matching values is many you can just pass a list of possible matches rather than writing a condition for  each

```
matches=['MK1','MA1']
df=df[df["Description_x"].apply(lambda x: x in matches)]
```

or in a single line

```
df=df[df["Description_x"].apply(lambda x: x in ['MK1','MA1'])]

or

MK1row =df[df["Description_x"].apply(lambda x: x=='MK1')]


MK2row =df[df["Description_x"].apply(lambda x: x=='MK2')]
```

Comment: Hi ,thanks for the reply.I just want to extract row using row value.not a cooling value.can you suggest me a solution for it

Comment: you will get two rows in the df
just access them by row no.s